# php generate links to all wordpress categories

Tags: php, wordpress

Im having a little problem. I want to display all categories connected to a wordpress post.

I found several codes and plugins, but all of them have problems. Some dont display correct anchor text, others dont link to correct url.
So i took the working parts from different places and put them together to the code below, and its working. 
The problem is that it does not generate links to ALL connected categories, it only show link to 1 single category (first one that was connected to the post)

what is wrong with the code ? Why will it not show links to all connected categories. I have been working on it for 2 days now, and i give up.

```html
<?php
$the_cat = get_the_category();
$category_name = $the_cat[0]->cat_name;
$category_link = get_category_link( $the_cat[0]->cat_ID );
?>
<?php 
global $post;
$category = reset(get_the_category($post->ID));
$category_id = $category->cat_ID;
?>
<a class="button" href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category_id ); ?>"title=”<?php echo $category_name ?>”  ><?php echo $category_name ?></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show the category that is related with the posts on post details page and archive page add this code in your child theme functions.php and call the function where you want to display it.

```
function postsCategories()
{
    $categories_list = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ', ', 'your-text-domain' ) );
    $allowed_tags_before_after=array('span' => array('class'=>array()),'i'=>array('class'=>array()),'a'=>array('class'=>array(),'href'=>array(),'rel'=>array()));

        if ( $categories_list )
        {
                printf(wp_kses(sprintf(__('<span class="blogmeta cat-links"> <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> %1$s </span>','your-text-domain'), $categories_list ),$allowed_tags_before_after)); 
        }
}
```

Call in the template : `<?php printf(__('%s','your-text-domain'),postsCategories()); ?>`

Answer (score 3):

Please try this code

```
<?php
$category_args_query = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'parent' => 0,
'hierarchical'  => 1,
'number'=> 10
);
$categories = get_categories( $category_args_query );?>
<ul>
    <?php 
    foreach ( $categories as $category ) 
    { ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->term_id ); ?> "><?php echo $category->name;  ?> </a></li> 
        <?php 
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your code display links to multiple categories, 10 links in total. But the links that are shown, is not categories connected to the post. They look to be the first 10 categories created in the database since they all start with the letter A.

Comment: Yes it will show 10 category by name order you can change the number value to show more category

Answer (score 0):

Actually just `<?php the_category(', ') ?>` should be enough (within the WP `while` loop). The `,` determines what should go in-between, if there is more than one category.